# NFS mount on Mac OS X 10.6.8 - Problem with special characters such as "á"

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, nas, nfs

On Snow Leopard, I used Disk Utility's "NFS Mount" feature to automatically mount a NFS shared folder from my Synology NAS.

Here are the Advanced Mount Parameters I used:

```
resvport,nolocks,locallocks,intr,soft,wsize=32768,rsize=3276,nosuid,-P
```

The shared folder mounts fine and performance is much better than what I was getting with AFP.

Problem is Finder/Path Finder can't read files on folders with non-standard characters, such as **í** or **á**.

Whenever I try to access them I get a "you don't have permission to read this file" error.

I can, however, access these files normally from the terminal. Any light on how to fix my Finder/Path Finder situation, please?

Comment: Apparently this is a Unicode Normalization Form issue for which there is no solution... This and other forum posts on Apple's support website made me conclude this:https://discussions.apple.com/message/10179275?messageID=10179275#10179275?messageID=10179275/ So sad, if anyone has any idea, I would greatly appreciate it!